# mingw shell in emacs

Tags: microsoft-windows, bash

i'd like to use bash shell from msys2 in emacs and i made the following changes in emacs init file:

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "C:/tools/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe")
(setq shell-file-name "bash")
(setq explicit-bash.exe-args '("--login" "-i"))
(setenv "SHELL" shell-file-name)
(setenv "BASH_ENV" "~/.bashrc")
(setq shell-command-switch "-c")
(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'comint-strip-ctrl-m)
```

the shell start and seems work but i got the following error:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When I run `M-x shell` in Emacs from the package `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-emacs` it reports warnings:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
tput: unknown terminal "emacs"
```

The reason is the Bash option `-i`, which is set by default:

```
(setq explicit-bash-args (list "-i"))
```

If you remove it the error disappears:

```lisp
(setq explicit-bash-args
      (if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
          (list "--login") ; On Windows -i is wrong!
        (list "-i")))
```

On Windows bash with `-i` attempts to configure terminal, but Emacs's `shell-mode` is not a terminal so `ioctl` reasonably fails!

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324986/bash-cannot-set-terminal-process-group-1-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090974/what-does-the-shcannot-set-terminal-process-group-1-inappropriate-ioctl-for
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72670239/inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-and-no-job-control-when-using-a-pty/

Comment: Without the `-i`, the shell is non-interactive, and there is no way to have it display command prompts (`PS1`) in the Emacs shell buffer.  Or is there a workaround?

Comment: The actual effect of `-i` is reading the file `~/.bashrc`. I suspect `PS1` is defined there. It is the reason of missing `PS1`. I have lots of useful settings in `~/.bashrc` so I keep `-i` and ignore warnings. There are no workarounds.